# Custom Date Filter is not returning anything Angular 8

Tags: angular-material, filtering, angular8, date-range

I am fairly new to Angular and have been trying to make a date range filter on the createDate column for my Mat Table. When I hit the filter button, it just populates a blank table. The code for the filter is in the constructor and the datFil(). I have tried a few different things but to no avail. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

TypeScipt

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { MatSort} from '@angular/material/sort';
import {MatPaginator} from '@angular/material/paginator';
import {MatTableDataSource} from '@angular/material/table';
import { MatDialog, MatDialogConfig } from '@angular/material';
import { DialogDataComponent } from "../dialog-data/dialog-data.component";
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';
import {FormControl, FormGroup} from '@angular/forms';



export interface User {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  distributor: string;
  storeNum: number;
  poNum: number;
  createDate: Date;
  recDate: Date;
  totalUnits: number;
}


@Component({
  selector: 'app-order-table',
  templateUrl: './order-table.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./order-table.component.scss']
})
export class OrderTableComponent implements OnInit{
  [x: string]: any;
  public users: User[];
  public begin: string;
  public end: string;
  private usersUrl = 'api/users';

  // public doFilter = (value: string) => {
  //   console.log("testing: " + value);

  //   this.dataSource.filter = value.trim().toLocaleLowerCase();
  // }


  displayedColumns: string[] = ['name', 'distributor', 'storeNum', 'poNum', 'createDate', 'recDate', 'totalUnits'];
  pipe: DatePipe;
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<User>(this.users);


  @ViewChild(MatPaginator, {static: false}) paginator: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort, {static: true}) sort: MatSort;

  storeFilter = new FormControl();
  poFilter = new FormControl();
  nameFilter = new FormControl();
  dateFilter = new FormControl();


  filteredValues = {
    name: '', distributor: '', storeNum: '',
    poNum: '', createDate: '', recDate: '', totalUnits: ''
  };




  constructor(private http: HttpClient, public dialog: MatDialog) {
    this.dataSource.filterPredicate = (data, filter) =>{
      if (this.begin && this.end) {
        return data.createDate >= this.fromDate && data.createDate <= this.toDate;
      }
      return true;
    }
  };


  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.pipe = new DatePipe('en');
    this.getUsers().subscribe(data => this.dataSource.data = data)
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;

    this.storeFilter.valueChanges.subscribe((storeFilterValue) => {
      this.filteredValues['storeNum'] = storeFilterValue;
      this.dataSource.filter = JSON.stringify(this.filteredValues);
    });

    this.poFilter.valueChanges.subscribe((poFilterValue) => {
      this.filteredValues['poNum'] = poFilterValue;
      this.dataSource.filter = JSON.stringify(this.filteredValues);
    });

    this.nameFilter.valueChanges.subscribe((nameFilterValue) => {
      this.filteredValues['name'] = nameFilterValue;
      this.dataSource.filter = JSON.stringify(this.filteredValues);
    });



    this.dataSource.filterPredicate = this.customFilterPredicate();
    console.log(this.dataSource);


  }


  dateFil(filter) {
    console.log(this.begin);
    console.log(this.end);
    this.dataSource.filter = ''+Math.random();

  }
```

HTML

```
<div>
  <input matInput class="dateRange" (keypress)="keyPressNumbersDate($event)" [formControl]= "dateFilter" [(ngModel)]= "begin" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy"> - <input matInput class="dateRange" (keypress)="keyPressNumbersDate($event)" [(ngModel)]= "end" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy">
  <button (click)= 'dateFil()'>Filter</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can jus filter your datasource like this.

```
 dateFil() {
   dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<User>(this.users.filter(x=>x.createDate>=this.begin && x.createDate<=this.end));
  }
```

I have created a demo you can find [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-table-data-source-6l8jlg?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: It is returning an error saying cannot read property filter of undefined